# Cannot complete ngrok tunnel connection on google colab

Tags: localhost, google-colaboratory, ngrok, pyngrok

I am trying to run ngrok and establish a connection on google colab. The code runs fine but I get the following error,

```
The connection to http://7f319cc47f9f.ngrok.io was successfully tunneled to your ngrok client, but the client failed to establish a connection to the local address localhost:80.

Make sure that a web service is running on localhost:80 and that it is a valid address.

The error encountered was: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:80: connect: connection refused
```

Now I am fairly new to ngrok and have little knowledge about how the servers work. So if any of you have a solution to this please give me a step by step solution. Also, I heard running the server fixes the problem but I am yet to find out how. I used port `8051`.

Answer (score 1):

In colab use localtunnel as

> !streamlit run /content/sparknlp_ner_playground.py & npx localtunnel
> --port 8503

Answer (score 0):

You are tunneling to port 80, but nothing is running there. As you mentioned port 8051, I assume that's where you mean to be tunneling. It seems you're using `pyngrok`, so [according to the docs](https://pyngrok.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integrations.html#colab-http-example) you would specify a port other than the default 80 like so:

```
ngrok.connect(8051)
```